# Has wampserver installed properly?

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I have downloaded wampserver, however I cannot open the application. When I do it comes back to the installation process. I see no icons thats changes colour. Have I installed the program incorrectly. Whats the best and easiest way?

I am trying to set phpmyadmin, however I am unable to do so, the information on the web seems to direct me towards installing wamp.

Are there other ways to get phpMyadmin locally?

I have successfully managed to install mysql and use this via command line.

Comment: If you already have MySQL installed. Backup your databases. and the uninstall MySQL Server. WAMPServer comes with MySQL but if you have 2 MySQL Servers on the same PC you will just get confused.

Answer (score 1):

### This is the simple run-down

1. **Download** wampserver from here [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper)
2. **Run** the installer all the way through
3. **Go to** 'unistall a program' in control panel and very wampserver is in the list
4. **Run** the application 'wampmanager.exe' should be in c:/wamp64/wampmanager
5. A **'W'** icon shoud be in the the **taskbar**, left-click>Restart all services, should be green now
6. Again left-click>**localhost** will take you to your homepage index.html
7. If you get **error 404 not found**, right-click>tools>test port 80 If it says its used by another application, go back to the same menu and click **"use a port other than 80"**, a windows comes up and type 8080, restart all services and repeat step 6.
8. Again left-click>**phpMyAdmin** will take you there, default password may be blank(as in empty) or 'root'